# How to make jQuery countdown a constant one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown

I created a little countdown (I know it is not the correct term but don't know what is). It counts from one number to another for a specific time.

```
<div class="headline"> 
  <p> How much remains to meet the goal? </p>
  </div>
<div class="loader">
  <span class="count">350000</span>
</div>

$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',336123).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 1728000000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

[You can see the code here:](https://codepen.io/petyoyo/pen/aVggJz)

The problem is that whenever the countdown is opened, these 20 days will start from this moment and from the originally assigned number.

How do I make the time start running from one moment run continuously, and when someone opens the page to see only the numbers that remain at the time of opening.

Excuse me for this bad explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you can take adventage of the Date() function which is available even on Vanilla javascript.

The Date object is used to work with dates and times.

Date objects are created with new Date().

I created a code for you, the only thing you need to do is to tweak the specific date that you want to countdown to on the second line.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 09, 2017 19:49:00").getTime(); //CHANGE HERE<----

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60))/1000 )+ //seconds
  (Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)))*60+ // min to sec
  (Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)))*60*60+ // hours to sec
  (Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)))*60*60*60; // days to sec

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
@background-color: #4684ee;
@loader-color: #fff;
@loader-size: 40vh;
@import '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers';
@headline: 40vh;

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}

body {
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.loader {
  color: #fff;
  
  font-family: Bangers, Menlo, Monaco, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: @loader-size;
  letter-spacing: 0.6rem;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.headline {
  font-family: Bangers, Menlo, Monaco, monospace;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="headline"> 
  <p> How much remains to meet the goal? </p>
 </div>
  <p class="loader" id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: @PemboPechi Hi, I wrote everything in the answer, you need to change in line number 2: var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 09, 2017 19:49:00").getTime();  <<<<<<<---- put here your specific date, also my answer uses native Javascript so you don't have to import jQuery lib.

Comment: Dude, thank you for the effort. This code counts the second, but I want to count the numbers from 340K to 350K for next 10 days.The point is to use this like a fake counter because I can not connect the sales with this counter I want to make a fake one with interval similar to sales amount per day. // I change my comment until you wrote yours//

Comment: // I change my comment until you wrote yours //

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to store a value somewhere, somehow.
Since you are only needing to store one `number` you do not need to make a new table if you do not have a database associated with the project [seems unlikely].

Anyway, assuming that you write to a table, the page somewhere, or a different file - you do the following:

// check `storage place` and see if there is a value (if not, this is the first run of the counter)

// If it is the first run, same current time to `storage place`; if not, get `starting time` from the `storage place`.

// Use this `starting time` and subtract it from the current time to get `elapsed time` and then subtract and return [display] the `remaining time`.

not difficult to implement in any number of ways, I would need more details though to give a better answer.

Comment: There is no table and unfortunately I don`t know how to store a number in table :/ Can you please explain me a little bit more.